# jQuery gridstack.js plugin: get "cell" width and height but keep it resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using [gridstack.js](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) to display a "layout" to users so they can build an ad page, and while I'm able to get the width and height of the cell after it's resized, as soon as the resize is done, the ability to resize the cell again is lost. Here is the HTML code I have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="editable">
      <div class="grid-stack">
        <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="2">
          <div class="grid-stack-item-content">2 x 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="2" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="3" data-gs-height="4">
          <div class="grid-stack-item-content">3 x 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
$('.grid-stack').gridstack({
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  cell_height: 60,
  vertical_margin: 20,
  animate: true,
  always_show_resize_handle: true
});

$('.grid-stack-item').on('resizestop', function() {
  var node = $(this).data('_gridstack_node');

  if(typeof node == undefined) {
      return;
  }

  $(this).html('<div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle">' + node.width + ' x ' + node.height + '</div>');
});
```

I was originally getting the `width` and `height` by just calling `$(this).data('gsWidth')` and `$(this).data('gsHeight')` but it would only retain the original attributes, and not the updated ones (even though the `HTML` code would change).

I want the user to see the new `W x H` value after (or while) they resize a "cell", but it's not working.

Here's a JSFiddle example so you can see what's going on (make sure your browser window is big enough):

http://jsfiddle.net/divspace/zsstqhee/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing with Gridstack.js for a while now, and decided to update this question with the answer. Here is the updated JavaScript:

```
$('.grid-stack').gridstack({
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  cell_height: 60,
  vertical_margin: 20,
  animate: true,
  always_show_resize_handle: true
});

var grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

$('.grid-stack-item').on('resizestop', function() {
  var gridCell = $(this),
      node = $(this).data('_gridstack_node');

  if(typeof node == undefined) {
    return;
  }

  grid.update(gridCell, node.x, node.y, node.width, node.height);

  $(this).find('.grid-stack-item-content').text(node.width + ' x ' + node.height);
});
```

And a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divspace/szLxc8sb/) example.